# Why is there a 1 next to "Watch" in github

Tags: github

I think the caption pretty much says it :)

What does one next to Watch mean?
[image]

Thanks in advance 
/peter

Comment: number of users that are paying attention to the repo (usually other participants in development, review, or anyone who wants to be notified of activity on the repo)

Comment: maybe the number of people who are watching the repo and want to receive notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks.

It seems to be the number of users that have selected to watch "All Activity".

Thanks clearing that up :)